# Unable to parse json string to object in pcl file in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I am downloading json string from a rest api and want to parse it to my object but I am getting following error:

> {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[{"Id":1,"Name":"Demo iManage School","ApiUrl":"http://demo.imanage-school.com/api/user/authenticatedUser/","LogoBytes":null},{"Id":2,"Name":"Al Omam International School","ApiUrl":"http://alomam.imanage-school.com/api/user/authenticatedUser/","LogoBytes":null}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[iManage.Models.SchoolModel]'. Path '', line 1, position 288. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[iManage.Models.SchoolModel].
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType) [0x00067] in <90125bc3858247a4a5e3af0c3035e4aa>:0 
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast (System.Object initialValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Type targetType) [0x00031] in <90125bc3858247a4a5e3af0c3035e4aa>:0 
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Type targetType) [0x0008d] in <90125bc3858247a4a5e3af0c3035e4aa>:0

My service code in PCL:

```
public void GetFeedItems(Action<List<SchoolModel>> success, Action<Exception> error)
    {
        var url = "http://demo.imanage-school.com/api/configurations/schoolnames";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(result => ProcessResponse(success, error, request, result), null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            error(exception);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessResponse(Action<List<SchoolModel>> success, Action<Exception> error, HttpWebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SchoolModel>>(text);
                success(objects);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            error(exception);
        }
    }
```

Model object:

```
public class SchoolModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public byte[] LogoBytes { get; set; }
}
```

My json:

> [{"Id":1,"Name":"Demo iManage School","ApiUrl":"http://demo-school.com/api/user/authenticatedUser/","LogoBytes":null},{"Id":2,"Name":"Al Omam International School","ApiUrl":"http://demo-school.com/api/user/authenticatedUser/","LogoBytes":null}]

I am using NewtonSoft for parsing.

Comment: That JSON parses fine, is it perhaps surrounded with double quotes?

Comment: Hi David, can you suggest a way to handle it?

Comment: Well... is the JSON surrounded by double quotes? So instead of `[{...}]` is it actually `"[{...}]"`? That's what the error seems to suggest.

Comment: No, Please check this url: http://demo.imanage-school.com/api/configurations/schoolnames

Comment: Yes, that response has surrounding quotes for me

Comment: but I don't see any quotes when I open this url in browser.

Comment: Well the browser shows you it surrounded by XML right?

Comment: Yes, so you mean browser removes the extra quotes in display

Comment: Look, debug your code, put a breakpoint on the `var objects = JsonConvert...` line and look at the value of `text` there - what is the exact content of it?

Comment: yes it has extra quotes there, so now either I have to remove it from my code or ask the web service person to remove it, Thanks David

Comment: I have removed first and last doublequote but now json becomes invalid, I get error: Invalid property identifier character: \. Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of additional double quotes around the json response. I removed it and it started working.